# Grails: Saving nested objects using XML data binding

Tags: xml, grails

I'm creating a REST service in Grails to accept data from a python script.  The python script generates an XML representation of the object graph and submits it to the controller.  Things work great for my flat objects, but I can't figure out how to handle the case where a domain object contains a Set of children objects.  For unrelated reasons, my DOA layer is pure Java JPA.

For example, my domain classes (Leaving out getters/setters/etc):

```
class Schedule {
  String name;
  @OneToMany;
  HashSet<Step> steps;
}

class Step {
    String name;
    @ManyToOne;
    Schedule schedule;
}
```

My python script generates XML like the following:

```
<schedule>
  <name>Foo</name>
  <steps>
     <step>
       <name>Bar</name>
     </step>
     <step>
        <name>Blatz</name>
     </step>
  </steps>
</schedule>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
def save = {
   def schedInstance = new Schedule(params['schedule'])
   ...
}
```

The steps property never gets populated. If I dump params out to a log the steps data is all jammed together (In my example above it would yield steps: "BarBlatz"

I have to be doing something terribly wrong.  I would imagine that this is a common task.  Everything I've been able to find about nesting objects is related to command objects. I don't want to have to duplicate my domain object code in a command object if I can avoid it.

Comment: if you have a time.. just give a shoot! and try generation an JSON file instead of an XML, and just let me know if it happens the same?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def save = {
    def schedInstance = new Schedule(params['schedule'])
    params['schedule?.step'].each{stepXml->
        schedInstance.addTo(new step(stepXml)
    }
}
```

Untested, but I've done something similar before . 
I'll edit this as needed as soon as I have a chance to test it.